# How to read all DICOM attributes/tags with pydicom?

Tags: python, pydicom

I'm trying to get a list of all the attributes (tags) of a given DICOM instance using pydicom.

The list should include the attribute key/id, its `vr`, the value, and also the corresponding name.

For example:

```
Tag: (2,0)
VR: UL
Name: File Meta Information Group Length
Value: 246
```

I'd like to get some guidance on how to obtain this information since I can't find anything useful in the pydicom docs.

My code is the following:

```py
import pydicom
from io import BytesIO

dicom_data = await client.download_dicom_file(image_id)
data = pydicom.dcmread(BytesIO(dicom_data))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get all tags, you just iterate over all elements in a dataset. [Here](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/auto_examples/input_output/plot_printing_dataset.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-input-output-plot-printing-dataset-py) is an example in the documentation that does that. It boils down to:

```py
from pydicom import dcmread

ds = dcmread(file_name)
for element in ds:
    print(element)
```

The example also shows how to handle sequences (by recursively iterating the sequence items). Here is a simple example for handling sequence items using just the string representation of the elements:

```py
def show_dataset(ds, indent):
    for elem in ds:
        if elem.VR == "SQ":
            indent += 4 * " "
            for item in elem:
                show_dataset(item, indent)
            indent = indent[4:]
        print(indent + str(elem))

def print_dataset(file_name):
    ds = dcmread(file_name)
    show_dataset(ds, indent="")
```

If you want to print your own representation of the data elements, you can access the element attributes.
Each element is a [DataElement](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/reference/generated/pydicom.dataelem.DataElement.html#pydicom.dataelem.DataElement),
which has the information you need:

```
>>> from pydicom import dcmread
>>> ds = dcmread("ct_small.dcm")  # from the test data
>>> len(ds)
258
>>> element = ds[0x00080008]
>>> element
(0008, 0008) Image Type                          CS: ['ORIGINAL', 'PRIMARY', 'AXIAL']
>>> type(element)
<class 'pydicom.dataelem.DataElement'>
>>> element.VR
'CS'
>>> element.tag
(0008, 0008)
>>> element.name
'Image Type'
>>> element.value
['ORIGINAL', 'PRIMARY', 'AXIAL']
>>> element.VM
3
```

You will find similar information in the documentation of [Dataset](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/reference/generated/pydicom.dataset.Dataset.html), and probably in other examples.

Note that there is also a [command line interface](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/guides/cli/cli_guide.html#pydicom-show-command) that shows the contents of a DICOM file.

*Edit*:
As this has been asked in the other answer: if you want to access the file meta information, e.g. the tags in group 2, you can do so by iterating over `ds.file_meta` (`ds` being the dataset). `file_meta` is also of type `Dataset` and can be accessed the same way. Note that `file_meta` may be `None` if no meta information is present in the dataset:

```py
from pydicom import dcmread

ds = dcmread(file_name)
file_meta = ds.file_meta
if file_meta is not None:
    for element in file_meta:
        print(element)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `to_json()`
https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/tutorials/dicom_json.html

Please note that for tags with group num 0x0002, pydicom cannot read them using `to_json()` and [MrBean Bremen's for-loop methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68320719/2745495). I am sorry that I have no solution for this limitation.

Comment: I added information about accessing the meta information in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for logging or user view, the default string representation of the dataset is the list of metadata, so `print(ds)`/`print(data)` is sufficient.

Note: original question named the dataset "data", most code examples use the variable name "ds" for datasets.